# Converting from ASIHTTPRequest to AFNetworking

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, asihttprequest, afnetworking

I am converting my app routines from ASIHTTP to AFNetworking due to the unfortunate discontinuation of work on that project ... and what I found out later to be the much better and smaller codebase of AFNetworking.

I am finding several issues.  My code for ASIHTTPRequest is built as a method.  This method takes a few parameters and posts the parameters to a url ... returning the resulting data.  This data is always text, but in the interests of making a generic method, may sometimes be json, sometimes XML or sometimes HTML.  Thus I built this method as a standalone generic URL downloader.

My issue is that when the routine is called I *have* to wait for a response.  I know all the "synchronous is bad" arguments out there...and I don't do it a lot... but for some methods I want synchronous.

So, here is my question.  My simplified ASIHTTP code is below, followed by the only way i could think of coding this in AFNetworking.  The issue I have is that the AFNetworking sometimes does not for the response before returning from the method.  The hint that @mattt gave of `[operation waitUntilFinished]` totally fails to hold the thread until the completion block is called... and my other method of `[queue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished]` does not necessarily always work either (and does NOT result in triggering the error portion of the [operation hasAcceptableStatusCode] clause).  So, if anyone can help, WITHOUT The ever-present 'design it asynchronously', please do.

**ASIHTTP version:**

```
- (NSString *) queryChatSystem:(NSMutableDictionary *) theDict
{
    NSString *response = [NSString stringWithString:@""];
    NSString *theUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",kDataDomain,kPathToChatScript];

    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theUrlString]];
    for (id key in theDict)
    {
        [request setPostValue:[theDict objectForKey:key] forKey:key];
    }

    [request setNumberOfTimesToRetryOnTimeout:3];
    [request setAllowCompressedResponse:YES];
    [request startSynchronous];

    NSError *error = [request error];
    if (! error)
    {
        response = [request responseString];
    }

    return response;
}
```

**AFNetworking version**

```
- (NSString *) af_queryChatSystem:(NSMutableDictionary *) theDict
{
    NSMutableDictionary *theParams = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:1];

    for (id key in theDict)
    {
        [theParams setObject:[theDict objectForKey:key] forKey:key];
    }


    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kDataDomain]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",kPathToChatScript] parameters:theParams];


    __block NSString *responseString = [NSString stringWithString:@""];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest] autorelease];

    operation.completionBlock = ^ {
        if ([operation hasAcceptableStatusCode]) {
            responseString = [operation responseString];
            NSLog(@"hasAcceptableStatusCode: %@",responseString);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"[Error]: (%@ %@) %@", [operation.request HTTPMethod], [[operation.request URL] relativePath], operation.error);
        }
    };

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] autorelease];
    [queue addOperation:operation];
    [queue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];
    [httpClient release];


    return responseString;

}
```

Thanks very much for any ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (void)af_queryChatSystem:(NSMutableDictionary *) theDict block:(void (^)(NSString *string))block {
...
}
```

Now within the completionBlock do:

```
block(operation.responseString);
```

block will act as the delegate for the operation. remove

```
-waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished
```

and

```
return responseString
```

You call this like:

```
[YourInstance af_queryChatSystem:Dict block:^(NSString *string) {
    // use string here
}];
```

Hope it helps. You can refer to the iOS example AFNetworking has

Comment: Yes, it did.  Thank you very much.  I am gonna have to learn more about blocks to begin to use them more.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend to use this opportunity to convert to Apple's own `NSURLConnection`, rather than adopt yet another third party API. In this way you can be sure it won't be discontinued. I have found that the additional work required to get it to work is **minimal** - but it turns out to be much more robust and less error prone.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, I would much rather, at this point, use AFNetworking.

Comment: I find your argument to be somewhat disingenuous in the way you dismiss 3rd party libraries. AFNetworking already has, at its core, a thin `NSOperation` wrapper around `NSURLConnection` that you're advocating. Why reinvent the wheel, and disregard the hundreds of hours of work the community has actively devoted to this library?

Comment: I see your point. My recommendation is based on personal experience. By no means was it dismissive. With code provided by the Apple examples, I have never needed significantly more lines of code. Many libraries provide simplification, but the developer still has to read API docs, only theirs instead of Apple's, a doubtful tradeoff. Now, with the "hundreds of hours of work" not supported any more, my recommendation is valid and made in good faith. Please consider removing your down vote.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is manually to run the current thread runloop until the callback have been processed.

Here is my code.

```
- (void)testRequest
{
    MyHTTPClient* api = [MyHTTPClient sharedInstance]; // subclass of AFHTTPClient
    NSDictionary* parameters = [NSDictionary dictionary]; // add query parameters to this dict.
    __block int status = 0;
    AFJSONRequestOperation* request = [api getPath:@"path/to/test"
                                        parameters:parameters
                                           success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                               // success code
                                               status = 1;
                                               NSLog(@"succeeded");
                                           } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                               // failure
                                               status = 2;
                                               NSLog(@"failed");
                                           }];
    [api enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:request];
    [api.operationQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];

    while (status == 0)
    {

        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode
                                 beforeDate:[NSDate date]];
    }

    STAssertEquals(status, 1, @"success block was executed");
}
```